# Firebase Cloud Messaging - Possible multiple notifications if token cancellation in my Backend fail

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a question about Token FCM.
Soppose to have an app, where many different user, on the same device, can do login and logout.
Supposing that process of `FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();` work perfectly and I will get correctly token device and refresh when data of app is cancelled and I will insert this value in my db.

I would that when current user logged do a Logout , I would to delete a token device that I have saved in my db because I have to send push notify from WebAPP.

But when the user try to Logout, the asynchronous Volley call to the backend that deals with the cancellation of token, returns an error. So I have done logout but I haven't deleted device token.

And second User do a Login on same device and get token device, that will be equals old token and so if I will push notify from my webApp, the current user logged will receive 2 notify, Also the one addressed to the other user.

So, there is a method for change always token or there is a method for have a new instance of token or Has anyone had the same problem?